# Best way to view excel files in blade views

Tags: excel, laravel, iframe

I currently generate excel files in my controller and store it in my storage path, thus I have an api to return the excel file but I want to let the user view it in the blade view. What is the best way or easiest way of doing this? Is putting the excel file in the iframe possible? As I know it is possible if the excel file is from the web and not from my own api/project path. The api that returns the excel file actually downloads the file straight away and does not just return the excel file's data

Comment: See if [this](https://handsontable.com/) suits you. It will help you get an excel-like interface. Alternatively, you can process the excel data and simply display the data in a table.

Comment: awesome thanks !! that works amazingly :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above...

You may use [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/) JavaScript plugin. It will help you get an excel-like interface.

Alternatively, you can process the excel data and simply display the data in a table